golang-jwt signature is invalid
Having some trouble validating jwt tokens using golang-jwt. Pretty sure I'm forming the tokens properly because I'm able to print them and they're being return fine, however when I try to parse them and extract the claims I'm getting an error saying signature is invalid.
I'm using the echo framework for my API, in case that matters.
This is my authentication middleware func

func validateJWT(tokenString string) (*jwt.Token, error) {
    // hard coded for now
    secretKey := "keepmesecret"

    return jwt.Parse(tokenString, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
        // Don't forget to validate the alg is what you expect:
        if _, ok := token.Method.(*jwt.SigningMethodHMAC); !ok {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("unexpected signing method: %v", token.Header["alg"])
        }

        // hmacSampleSecret is a []byte containing your secret, e.g. []byte("my_secret_key")
        return []byte(secretKey), nil
    })
}

func Authenticator(next echo.HandlerFunc) echo.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c echo.Context) error {
        // Get the token from the header
        tokenString := strings.Split(c.Request().Header.Get("Authorization"), "Bearer ")[1]
        token, err := validateJWT(tokenString)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return c.JSON(401, map[string]interface{}{
                "error": "Invalid token",
            })
        }
        if !token.Valid {
            return c.JSON(401, map[string]interface{}{
                "error": "Invalid token",
            })
        }

        claims := token.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims)

        // Set the user in the context
        c.Set("user", claims["username"])

        return next(c)
    }
}

This is my token creation
func createToken(secretKey string, username string) (string, error) {
    claim := jwt.MapClaims{
        "username": username,
        "exp":      time.Now().Add(time.Hour * 24).Unix(),
    }

    token := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.SigningMethodHS256, claim)

    tokenString, err := token.SignedString([]byte(secretKey))
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    return tokenString, nil
}

func sendToken(c echo.Context, secretKey string, username string) error {
    token, err := createToken(secretKey, username)

    if err != nil {
        return c.String(500, "Internal Server Error")
    }
    return c.String(200, token)
}

// login
func RouteLogin(c echo.Context) error {
    
    secretKey := "keepmesecret"

    username := c.FormValue("username")
    password := c.FormValue("password")

    // if username is not admin get all guest account info
    if username == "admin" {
        if password != settings.Accounts.Admin.Password {
            return c.String(401, "Unauthorized")
        } else {
            sendToken(c, secretKey, username)
        }
    } else {
        accounts := settings.Accounts.GuestAccounts
        account, ok := accounts[username]
        if !ok {
            return c.String(404, "Not Found")
        }
        if account.Password != password {
            return c.String(401, "Unauthorized")
        }
        sendToken(c, secretKey, username)
    }

    return c.String(200, "login")
}

Adding some log info
Sending token:  eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE3MTUwNjExMzUsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiZ3Vlc3QifQ.hbF88eu6fGs6F0S9Ttvv6eu8_mT_Iv7rBHvGq8Epvrw using secret key:  Indisputably-Salty-Orbit-7260-07erijgpeirgjpejgptrjgpptgjpritgpi4rtnghi
2024-05-06T15:52:15+10:00 | 200 | 2.5633ms | 127.0.0.1 | POST /api/auth/login
Received token:  eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE3MTUwNjExMzUsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiZ3Vlc3QifQ.hbF88eu6fGs6F0S9Ttvv6eu8_mT_Iv7rBHvGq8Epvrwlogin using secret key:  Indisputably-Salty-Orbit-7260-07erijgpeirgjpejgptrjgpptgjpritgpi4rtnghi
signature is invalid
2024-05-06T15:52:24+10:00 | 401 | 2.7255ms | 127.0.0.1 | GET /api/navigate/?pathname=/


Have you confirmed that the token received in validateJWT matches the one sent in sendToken? Also check that secretKey is identical in these two functions (we cannot see where this is coming from). Unfortunately there is not enough information here to help (really need a reproducible example)

@Brits Hi, yes the secretKey is coming from the same file. so I'm certain it's the same, however for the purpose of the question I've hard coded it. I am also sure the token is the same in both places since I'm copy pasting while testing the functions. I'm not sure what other information would be relevant here.

Add some logging and give us an example of the value of tokenString in Authenticator (the actual value, not what you assume it to be) along with the full error returned by jwt.Parse.  Your code to create and validate the token works so I'd guess the issue is elsewhere (or your example code excludes something). "since I'm copy pasting" but your server code is parsing the key so there is room for error (unless we can duplicate your failing test it's hard to help - there is nothing obviously wrong with your code but there is a lot missing).

@Brits Thanks so much for your debugging steps, I've added some logging information, although it appears to be the exact string, it seems a "login" string is being appended at the end somewhere, seems like I need to return my sendToken function, so that the last c.String() method is not called. I'm quite used to nodejs throwing an error when I try to write to the response after something has already been sent, I suppose go(echo) doesn't do that? Would you like to create an answer with these findings?... I'll be happy to accept

No worries, I don't think that an answer would be particularly useful to others (as it's not really clear where the "login" is being appended, and I don't think it's in the code in the question). I guess the lesson is that it's always worth adding logging to ensure that data is as you expect.

Yup sure. Thanks anyway. PS: it is in the code above... in the RouteLogin function, where I'm calling sendToken(c, secretKey, username)... it should be return sendToken(c, secretKey, username)

Thanks for pointing that out, totally missed it!

As per the comments the issue was here :
    } else {
...
        sendToken(c, secretKey, username)
    }

    return c.String(200, "login")

sendToken called c.String(200, token) which sends transmits the contents of the string to the client. The implementation of String calls Blob which writes the header (will warn if this has already been done) and then the data. Because String is being called twice (once in sendToken and then again in return c.String) the output will be the token with login appended (i.e. eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE3MTUwNjExMzUsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiZ3Vlc3QifQ.hbF88eu6fGs6F0S9Ttvv6eu8_mT_Iv7rBHvGq8Epvrwlogin).
So the token sent to the client has the text login appended and this means you will get an error when you attempt to parse it. The simplest way to find issues like this is often just adding logging to check that the value you have is what you expect.
